# Retrieving a column, assign to it a variable from a SQL stored procedure using PYODBC and python and having no [ ] or ' ' in the variable

Tags: python-3.x, variables, stored-procedures, pyodbc

This site has been such a help to me while learning Python and after wrestling with this issue on and off for the last 3 days its defeated me and I bet its such an easy fix. The below code works fine, as its producing no errors except it has one annoying issue and I cannot seem to find away around it, okay code below.

```
    import pyodbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect('{dsn connection}')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    storedprocedure = "sql stored procedure retrieving all columns and adding one parameter ?"
    #taking a value from a previous column to pass into sql query
    params = idno 
    
    cursor.execute(storedprocedure, params)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
   
    column1 = [row[0] for row in result]    
    
    #Check result in variable
    print(column1)
```

As you can see its simple program but when I print column1 this is the output in python :

```
['Lawrence']
```

so naturally I can use

```
print(*column1, sep = '')
```

and get this output which is what I want in the variable

```
Lawrence
```

The question is how do I get that value into the variable without those annoying [' '] its so frustrating. I am then using that variable and putting into code to insert into an SQL database and then running web reports from that which all works but obviously displaying the square brackets but only for the information taken from this query the other variables I taken from forms work fine. I have tried various methods of retrieving the information from the database and they all do the same thing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I have been googling and testing various things and having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

SIGH fixed the issue and I new it was simple, the [' and '] are spaces which are being filled in automatically. So change how I create the variable to a string and use the strip command to remove the spaces. I also changed it to cusor.fetchone as the query i`m posting will only bring back one response.

```
result = cursor.fetchone()

column1 = str(result[0]).strip()   

#Check result in variable
print(column1)
```

This brings back what I want no [' or '] anywhere now hope this helps someone out.

Comment: You can do it all automatically by using `.fetchval()` instead of `.fetchone()`

Comment: Have not heard of that before, quick google and fetchval() returns the first column? Thanks for comment though always looking for a better way to do things

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fetchval

Comment: Cheers Gord handy to know that for future